# Change Colors (onclick) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, debugging

I was coding a website and was trying to change a few colors and pictures onclick using JavaScript to change the CSS. However this code is only partially working. Only the "txtArea" field changes color. Checked the validators and consoles its perfect syntax.??

```
<!-- This is the button to change the color, Its 1 bulletin point. -->
<div id="colorSelector"><span id="chngBlue"><a href="#" onclick="chngColor()">&bull;</a></span> &bull; &bull;</div>

<script>
var colors = ["#0099cc", "#669900", "#993333"];//Blue, Green, Red

function chngColor(){
document.getElementById("txtArea").style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr").style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
document.getElementById("newLink").style.color = colors[2];
document.getElementById("hdBanner").src='bannerred.png';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Reading [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) is always useful. You should also check the console (hit F12), there's an error message waiting for you.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks "the docs" did help with making my code a little shorter. But I seem to be following all guidelines acording to that and no error messages in the console. I even did a double take of the tag ID's. hmm ..

Comment: There has to be an error message. You're trying to set `collection.style.backgroundColor`, The collection doesn't have `style` property, and setting `backgroundColor` of `null` will definitely trigger an error. See the given answers, they all explain, how to get the members of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr") return a HTMLCollection (Thanks @Teemu for the clarification), so it haven't 'style'. You can do something like

```
var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr"); 

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) { 
    myElements[i].style.color = colors[2]; 
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't return an array of elements, it returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: In any case we need something like

var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.color = colors[2];
}

Comment: Yep, please put that into ypur post. Notice, that you can't use forexample `forEach` to iterate the collection, since it is not an array. That's why it's important to know what kind  of an object you're working with.

Comment: @aleksejjj Oh I understand. So you guys are saying that since my **getElementsByClassName** class returns more than one element I have to speratley script each using a **for loop**.

Answer (score 0):

*getElementsByClassName* returns an *array-like object*, so you need to index into this array even if it only contains one element.

So the second line of the function becomes:

`document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr")[0].style.backgroundColor = colors[2];`

http://codepen.io/markwill/pen/rrAXzr

If there is more than one element with this class you'll need to iterate over all of them setting the style (this is safer than just assuming that there's just one).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
function chngColor(){
    document.getElementById("txtArea").style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
    document.getElementsByClassName("labHdr").style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
    document.getElementById("newLink").style.color = colors[2];
    document.getElementById("hdBanner").src='bannerred.png';
}
```

By that:

```
function chngColor(){
    var labelList = document.querySelectorAll(".labHdr");
    document.getElementById("txtArea").style.backgroundColor = colors[2];
    document.getElementById("newLink").style.color = colors[2];
    document.getElementById("hdBanner").src='bannerred.png';

    Array.prototype.map.call(labelList, function(element) { 
        element.style.backgroundColor = colors[2]; 
    });

}
```

With this all your labels will be change.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get element by id for change color below example which get more idea

```
<h1 id="id1">My Heading 1</h1>
<button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">
Click Me!</button>
```